# How to excecute stored procedure with parameter in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My procedure is like this:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE rs_pes (c1                IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                    pi_prod_type_code IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pi_entry_date     IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pi_dealer         IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pi_adv            IN VARCHAR2 )
```

And, I'm trying to execure it like this:

```
execute  RS_PES('Investments Series 2',
        '31-12-2012',
        'All Dealer',
        'All Adv')
```

I'm getting incorrect syntax error.

```
ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement
00900.00000 - Invalid SQL statement
```

What I'm doing wrong, how to execute this? I'm new to Oracle.

Comment: you forgot brackets. Parameters are specified in brackets

Comment: Even throgh I give bracket, it gives me same error.I have modified my question.

Comment: What are you using to execute?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Sql developer.

Comment: I think I have missed semicolon. after giving this, I'm not getting any error. But, meanwhile, I'm not getting any result, is it because, may be I do not have permission for this? Then, why its not showing any message, that, i do not have permission; just like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

[Execute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm#BACFGDHC) is a SQL*Plus command which basically wraps your procedure call around BEGIN/END statements. This won't work anywhere else except SQL*Plus

If you want to execute the procedure in Oracle SQL Developer, wrap it in BEGIN/END block

```
BEGIN
 RS_PES('Investments Series 2',
        '31-12-2012',
        'All Dealer',
        'All Adv');

END;
```

Also, your procedure has 5 parameters, while you're setting only 4. You need to fix that.